# Rejecting an app that is Pending Developer Release

Tags: iphone, release

I have an update to my app that has been reviewed and is **Pending Developer Release**.

I have found a bug in this version and would actually like to reject this binary and keep my existing binary.

Once I fix the bug, I would like to re-upload a new binary. Is this possible?

Answer (score 55):

It took me a little while to find the answer to this. It can be done, but the answer isn't very intuitive.

In iTunes Connect, select your new application & load the details for it. Click the "Binary Details" link. Once this screen is open, there will be a "Reject this Binary" button on this screen.

I found this within the [iTunes Developer guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)(Link PDF has only 1 page and no other information) under the Rejecting Your Binary section. Apple really could have made the button more obvious.

> **Note :** Link PDF has only 1 page and no other information

Comment: After you reject your binary, you can then edit the Version information under the title of the app to increase/decease the version number if you need to.

Comment: Just wanted to check on this - does doing this send your new binary to the back of the review queue or can you basically release the new binary immediately without it going through review again?

Answer (score 27):

Attaching screenshots from the App Store Connect (previously known as iTunes Connect) interface:

Select the version, then click on "cancel this release"

> You can only edit some information while your version is pending developer release. To edit all information, **cancel this release**.

[image: Stor]

You will be prompted with a confirmation dialog:

> Are you sure you want to cancel the release of version 2.6?
>
> If you cancel this release, you must choose a new binary and resubmit this app version. Your version will be reviewed again by App Review.

[image: Cancel Release dialog]

Comment: Does this mean I can replace the binary without changing the version or the Build number ?  So it is like submitting for App review all over again although with a new binary but same version ?

Comment: will it be replacing?

Comment: @Dibzmania You will be able to use the same binary you rejected, you do not need to change the build number. I just did this because I forgot to update the description. ha

Answer (score 9):

Explanation to kernix answer:

- select app in itunesconnect;
- select app version;
- you will see "You can only edit some information while your version is pending developer release. To edit all information, cancel this release." at the top of the page. Just click on "cancel this release" link.

Answer (score 3):

From the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide:](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)

NOTE: You can only use the Version Release Control on app updates. It is not available for the first version of your app since you already have the ability to control when your first version goes live, using the Availability Date setting within Rights and Pricing. If you decide that you do not want to ever release a Pending Developer Release version, you will need to click the Release This Version button anyway, in order to create a new version of your app. You are not permitted to skip over an entire version.

Comment: This answer is outdated. It is possible to cancel a pending release right now.