# Can I remove app from "Pending Developer Release"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My iOS app is currently "Pending Developer Release". I did this to get promo codes. With promo codes, I got some awesome feedback from users. I want to implement those changes and add it to app. So how do I remove my app from "pending developer release" since anyways it's not in app store now. Also, if next week I add the changes and upload this new app build, would App store have a problem with it and think it's a duplicate so they wouldn't allow it to be uploaded to App store?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rejecting an app that is Pending Developer Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792402/rejecting-an-app-that-is-pending-developer-release)

Answer (score 2):

> Also, if next week I add the changes and upload this new app build, would App store have a problem with it and think it's a duplicate so they wouldn't allow it to be uploaded to App store?

There are two build numbers:

[image]

Increase the *second* build number but leave the *first* build number the same. That way, the App Store knows that this is an update to the same build. And when it has processed, you can then release the later build.

Comment: So I can press "cancel this release" to my current build in "pending developer release". Then the updated build I'd have to increase the version and build number and upload that for review? It'd be ok? No issues with App store review?

Comment: My experience is that I withdrew a binary after submitting for review, because I discovered a bug, and did what I said in my answer, and there was no problem.

Comment: Should I upload with same version new build directly or reject the binary first?