# In iTunes Connect, can an app version be the same when canceling a version in Pending Developer Release and uploading a new build?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have a situation in which I need to update the current developer pending release build without changing my app version to the App Store.

We have release 1.0.0 in iTunes Connect and it's not published, but Apple approved the build so it is in the Pending Developer Release status.

So the question is if I cancel this version in the Pending Developer Release status and upload a new build, could my app version (1.0.0) be same or do I need to compulsory change the app version (e.g. 1.0.1)? I don't want to change the app version.

Let me know if it is possible and if anyone have experienced the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, you can keep the current version number after rejecting the current release build.

For more information about rejecting a version in the Pending Developer Release state, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3792402/3151675).